# @Local and @Remote interfaces - Pass by reference vs deep copy

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

We have an app with the with three interfaces per bean. A `*BI` (business interface) which contains all the methods, a `*LI`, which extends `BI` and is annotated as `@Local`, and `*RI`, which also extends `BI`, but is annotated as `@Remote`.

I want to remove all `*LI` and `*RI` interfaces in favor of `*BI`, leaving they as `@Remote`, but there is a problem.

Local lookup pass arguments as references, while remote lookup uses deepcopy. The app is full of pass-by-reference expectations (things that only works if pass by reference works).

If I have only `@Remote` interfaces, the container will know when it is a local lookup and make pass-by-reference works in that case?

Container is JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final and we use EJB 3.1.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the local and remote interfaces behave differently even a local client could want to use the remote interface. So it would be a problem if the container just guessed "this client is running in the same VM, let's give him a local interface".

Details on the differences were already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385717/why-do-we-need-separate-remote-and-local-interfaces-for-ejb-3-0-session-beans).

If you want to keep all your interface definitions in one place simply write an interface
and let it be inherited by two (empty) interfaces annotated with `@Local` and `@Remote`.

Comment: Well, seems like I will have to do a small refactoring in some old code.. thanks =)